# How to troubleshoot Ubuntu One in Maverick beta?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one

I just updated to the Maverick beta (actually it's a fresh install, and not an upgrade of 10.04).  But now "Ubuntu One" doesn't show up in my me-menu thing.  In addition, when I go to Ubuntu One from System->Preferences and attempt to log in from there it will sometimes look like it works, but other times it won't do anything.  When I go to the command line and type u1sdtool -s it will either say something like "doing auth dance" or "auth failed" and often it has never even prompted me to log in or try to get a new password (even though I know it's correct).

Anyway, this is the main hangup I have with the Maverick beta.  I can't get to my ubuntu one account from the native client.

Is this a widespread issue? Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: I can't work out what you are asking - please rephrase as a question. Remember that Maverick is still in beta and shouldn't be used apart from for testing. If you find any problems like this, please report them as bugs in launchpad.

Comment: Basically I want to know if this is a widespread issue, or if there is something I can do to fix it.  It may be something I'm doing wrong, so I'd like to try all possible suggestions before I go and report a bug.  Ubuntu one wont let me log in or sync.

Comment: I don't personally know how to fix this problem. I would advise reporting the bug - just try to gather as much information about any errors/logs/etc. If it is your mistake, the developers should be able to tell you what to do and they will just mark your bug 'Invalid'. Also it might prompt them to adjust the program so that people can't make the same mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Ubuntu One team welcome any testing support that you can provide. If you encounter a problem during an Ubuntu alpha or beta phase, please file bugs at our Launchpad site.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client

Before filing a bug, though, it would be helpful if you search/scan over the existing bugs in order to reduce duplicates.

The issues that you point out have already been reported so we're working on them ;) They should be revolved very soon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issues at one point, iirc these steps fixed it for me... but I can't test it atm.

1. Quit the Ubuntu One client (open a terminal window & run "u1sdtool -q; killall ubuntuone-login" without the quotes)

   1. Open Applications->Accessories->Passwords and Encryption Keys
   2. Click on the plus symbol next to "Passwords: login" to expand the list
   3. Right-click on the Ubuntu One token and select "Delete"
   4. Go to https://one.ubuntu.com/account/machines/
   5. Click on the checkbox next to your computer
   6. Click the "Remove selected computers" button
   7. Open System --> Preferences -->Ubuntu One
   8. a web page should open, prompting you to add your computer to your Ubuntu One account
   9. Add your computer