# Ubuntu One says I'm out of Space

Tags: ubuntu-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to troubleshoot Ubuntu One in Maverick beta?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3673/how-to-troubleshoot-ubuntu-one-in-maverick-beta)

Ubuntu One does not sync my files. It always keeps saying that I'm out of space. Well, I have no files, 1 contact and 8 notes on the server. Nothing Else.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate at all. Other question is different, a non-accepted answer is referenced here, but that didn't work. Can't / shouldn't add my answer to that question, as it is not an answer to that question. This should be re-opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just followed the answer by Eternal Wolf here: [How to troubleshoot Ubuntu One in Maverick beta?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3673/how-to-troubleshoot-ubuntu-one-in-maverick-beta)

and it seems to work.